# regex for match out of two characters where @ is the only character or preceded by a whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex where I am always comparing the most recent typed characters to the regex and trying to match only '@' when nothing is before it and ' @'

I am trying to use:

```
lastTwoEntered.match(/(\s|^)@/);
```

and

```
lastTwoEntered.match( /^\B@/);
```

but they both are inaccurate.

the following should not return true:
'a@'
'@d'
'@@'
'  '
'@ '

Comment: i only want to get '@' and ' @'

Comment: Your title says "followed by a whitespace" but your example shows it being preceded by a whitespace. In any case, you're using `^` to mark the beginning of the string; all you need to do is add `$` at the end of your first one and it should work.

Comment: https://regex101.com/#javascript is a **very** useful tool.

Comment: What is the context of this?  Are you trying to match name tags kinda like twitter?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you trying to do:

/^@$|^ @$/

the "$" means that it ends with @

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
lastTwoEntered.match( /^ ?@$/);
```

The question symbol matches the space 0 or 1 times. There are other useful quantifiers you can find  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
To understand thoroughly why this works you should understand greedy and lazy matching. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is a good post explaining it. 
Let's just say that the matcher will attempt to match the biggest valid string for your regex.

---

So, for the first regex you provide the match would be:

**anything, space, at,anything**

or

**beginning of line, at , anything**

The second matches:

**beginning,anything but boundary,at,anything**

None of this is what you want.

It is a good practice to translate your regex to normal speech to be sure it is what you want.